# libreelec docker in .config/autostart.sh not working propely

Tags: docker, autostart, libreelec

when I run

```
docker exec -i -t transmission  df -h /media/TOSHIBA_HD/home-theater/
```

from /storage/.config/autostart.sh I don't get any output at all
if I run it from ssh I get

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           374M  2.6M  372M   1% /media/TOSHIBA_HD/home-theater
```

which I can use to know if transmission is mapped correctly or needs a restart

I am hitting my head against the wall, trying to figure out why my bash SSH terminal works nicely but the autostart.sh doesn't
both run as root, I redirected the output to a log to see looped waiting a second - checking it again and again - and while my shell showed the correct output, autostart.sh STILL gives no output

Answer (score 0):

turns out it was a flag issue, instead of running:

```
docker exec -i -t transmission  df -h /media/TOSHIBA_HD/home-theater/
```

I need to run:

```
docker exec -i transmission  df -h /media/TOSHIBA_HD/home-theater/
```

without the -t flag which requires a terminal.

found this out by searching the error “The input device is not a TTY”
here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099116/error-the-input-device-is-not-a-tty